# How do I obtain the text on a span inside div with selenium on python.

Tags: html, web-scraping

I'm making a selenium script on python that goes to a classifieds page, obtains the info of one of my posts, deletes it and the repost it. However I'm stuck here: Is there a way of getting the text inside the following html, and saving either as a local variable inside the script or as a text file?

The thing is, I'm trying to make the script generic, and since the text in my post vary, Im not sure if finding by xpath will work. Is there a way to target the div by its id, and returning the text inside it?

```
<div id="UserContent">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span itemprop="description">
                    "Text I need" 
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is irrelevant, you should be using the id etc..:

```
"//*[@id='UserContent']//span[@itemprop='description']//text()"
```

So in selenium:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='UserContent']//span[@itemprop='description']").text
```

Or use a css selector:

```
 text = driver.find_element_by_css("#UserContent span[itemprop=description]").text
```

An example use *lxml*:

```
In [12]: from lxml import html
In [13]: h  = """<div id="UserContent">
   ....: <table>
   ....:     <tbody>
   ....:         <tr>
   ....:             <td>
   ....:                 <span itemprop="description">
   ....:                     "Text I need"
   ....:                 </span>
   ....:                  <span itemprop="foo">bar</span>
   ....:             </td>
   ....:         </tr>
   ....:     </tbody>
   ....: </table>
   ....: </div>
   ....: 
   ....: """
In [14]: tree = html.fromstring(h)   
In [15]: print(tree.cssselect("#UserContent span[itemprop=description]")[0].text)

                    "Text I need"   
In [16]: print(tree.xpath("//*[@id='UserContent']//span[@itemprop='description']//text()")[0])

                    "Text I need"


In [17]:
```

Comment: Works perfectly, however the expression:

text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='UserContent']//span[@itemprop='description']//text()").text

Gave me an "is: [object Text]. It should be an element.". I assume its because the inner "text()" at the end of the xpath was redundant with the .text outside, After removing it, it wokerd wonders. Thank you very much

Comment: No prob, I was mixing lxml and selenium syntax with the text() and .text